# How can I customize vehicles I can't customize?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I've recently acquired a Crusader tank for my garage:
[image: Crusader]

It is very oppressive and white, and I would like to give it a paint job. However, like many authority vehicles it is apparently "not customizable". I'd leave it at that, if I were not previously able to customize a different kind of "not customizable" vehicle:
[image: Purple challenger]

I can assure you that the Challenger tank does not usually come in purple, but I can't for the life of me remember just how I managed to get it looking like that. Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just have the [purple tank DLC?](http://store.steampowered.com/app/55398/)

Comment: @agent86 Wrong tank. The DLC is a purple Crusader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a glitch you can abuse that will allow you to customise vehicles that are tagged as non-customisable.

First, leave the vehicle you wish to customise in a garage. Then, take any customisable vehicle to a Rim Jobs. Once you get into the customisation menu, press Garage and highlight the vehicle you want to customise. **Without actually selecting the vehicle**, exit the menu, and answer in the affirmative when it asks you for confirmation. You will now be in the customisation menu for the vehicle you highlighted.

Edit: According to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiGGf1wW0xE), this glitch will not work with all vehicles driven into the Rim Jobs; only some will work for each, with the exception of the Gat Mobile, which will allow you to customise any vehicle.

Comment: That does indeed work, though sadly not even the Gat Mobile will allow me to customize S.T.A.G. vehicles.

Answer (score 6):

If you're playing on the PC, you can install the **[Extended Customization](http://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/extended-customization-v1-2-now-with-more-helis.470/)** mod which will allow you to customize all vehicles (including planes and helicopters) - even those not allowed to be customized by the vanilla game. Note that this mod is already part of the [Things To Do In Steelport](https://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/things-to-do-in-steelport-family-friendly-edition.12334/) mod compilation (which I recommend you install, instead of the standalone version). That mod compilation also contains other game fixes and improvements.

Screenshots of vehicles customized with Extended Customization:

[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score -1):

Get a gatmobile and go to a rim jobs and go to garage in the menu and click on a non customizable car press back and press up and then press ok.